# SQL statement to Join one Parent to three Child tables

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I have a application which has one Parent table and three Child tables. For argument sake lets call the tables Parent, Child1, Child2 and Child3. The tables contain the following columns:

```
Parent: Key, Desc
Child1: Key, ParentKey, Date, AccessCount
Child2: Key, ParentKey, Date, AssceeCount
Child3: Key, ParentKey, Date, AccessCount
```

I am trying to create an SQL query in Visual Basic which, for a specified Parent.Key range, will give me Sum(Child1.AccessCount) as Child1-Total, Sum(Child2.AccessCount) as Child2-Total, Sum(Child3.AccessCount) as Child3-Total, for a specified date range.

I want the output to look something like this:

```
ParentKey ParentDesc Child1-Total Child2-Total Child3-Total
```

So far, I have tried the following Visual Basic SQL statement:

```
Select Parent.Key as [ParentKey], Parent.Desc as [ParentDesc],
   Sum(Child1.AccessCount) as [Child1-Total],
   Sum(Child2.AccessCount) as [Child2-Total],
   Sum(Child3.AccessCount) as [Child2-Total],
From ((Parent
   Inner Join Child1 On (Parent.Key = Child1.ParentKey
                     And Child1.Date >= #01/01/2013#
                     And Child1.Date <= #31/12/2014#))
   Inner Join Child2 On (Parent.Key = Child2.ParentKey
                     And Child2.Date >= #01/01/2013#
                     And Child2.Date <= #31/12/2014#))
   Inner Join Child3 On (Parent.Key = Child3.ParentKey
                     And Child3.Date >= #01/01/2013#
                     And Child3.Date <= #31/12/2014#)
Where Parent.Key >=5 And Parent.Key <= 25
Group By Parent.Key, Parent.Desc
```

My Visual Basic SQL statement produces incorrect result, so I would love to have someone point me in the right direction and help me generate SQL which will give the correct result. NB: I know that the above statement is not valid VB because "line continuation" is missing.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: This looks like MS Access.  If so, the question should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: Gordon, my apologies, you are correct. The SQL I am writing is for MS Access (using OBDC driver for DBF database). I will tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Do the aggregation using subqueries.  Assuming you are using MS Access, the query is something like this:

```
select p.key, nz(cnt1, 0) + nz(cnt2, 0) + nz(cnt3, 0)
from (((parent as p left join
        (select parentkey, sum(accesscount) as cnt1
         from child1
         where Child1.Date >= #01/01/2013# And Child1.Date <= #31/12/2014#
        ) as c1
        on c1.parentkey = p.key
       ) left join
       (select parentkey, sum(accesscount) as cnt2
        from child2
        where Child2.Date >= #01/01/2013# And Child2.Date <= #31/12/2014#
       ) as c2
       on c2.parentkey = p.key
      ) left join
      (select parentkey, sum(accesscount) as cnt3
       from child3
       where Child3.Date >= #01/01/2013# And Child3.Date <= #31/12/2014#
      ) as c3
      on c2.parentkey = p.key;
```

EDIT:

I didn't realize MS Access doesn't allow subqueries in the `from` clause -- all the more reason to change to another database.

You can do this with correlated subqueries in the `select`:

```
select p.key,
       nz( (select sum(accesscount) 
            from child1
            where Child1.Date >= #01/01/2013# And Child1.Date <= #31/12/2014# and
                  Child1.parentkey = p.key
           ), 0) as cnt1,
       nz( (select sum(accesscount)
            from child1
            where Child2.Date >= #01/01/2013# And Child2.Date <= #31/12/2014# and
                  Child2.parentkey = p.key
           ), 0) as cnt2,
       nz( (select sum(accesscount)
            from child3
            where Child3.Date >= #01/01/2013# And Child3.Date <= #31/12/2014# and
                  Child3.parentkey = p.key
           ), 0) as cnt3
from parent as p;
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, MS-Access does not appear to allow sub-queries on joins. It consistently reports "syntax error in JOIN expression".